# Selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Command execution failure

Tags: selenium, command, execution

Please search the forum at http://clearspace.openqa.org for error details from the log window.  The error message is: Permission denied

I am getting error when i am trying to execute `Selenium.IsElementPresent(ticketLocator)`

Help me!!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah got the answer.
Basically with the selenium I was clicking a button and then directly calling this

```
Selenium.IsElementPresent(ticketLocator)
```

and not waiting for the page to load.

```
Selenium.Click(elementId);
Selenium.WaitForPageToLoad(milliseconds.ToString()); // milliseconds
```

So now after clicking I am waiting for 3 seconds and it started working fine.